# Projection Matrix - Horizontal Perspective, Vertical Orthographic

Tags: math, camera, perspective, orthographic, projection-matrix

Is it possible to create a projection matrix that is horizontally perspective, yet vertically orthographic?  I am trying to create a game in Unity (2D) and am just learning about projection matrices.  If you look at an engine like Construct 2, it has this capability baked in by default (as you can set parallax based on the x and y axis).  Now, I know this can be done with an orthographic camera and scripts to move the backgrounds, but I was wondering if it can be done with a perspective camera.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a way. At least not with the notation of homogeneous matrices. The problem is that both x and y are divided by a common denominator. If you want to cancel this out for y, you will get a non-affine map, which is not representable with a homogeneous matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nico. :)
I ended up going with a orthographic camera and a script that moved the gameobjects accordingly...